# How to generate a new Redeem code on TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a new iOS device and want to install one of my applications on it to test it. The problem is that I used the redemption code on another device long ago and I don't find the email I received from the App Store Connect.

So, I removed my email from my tester's group and added it again. I received a new email from App Store Connect and the link to download the app. However, I received the following message when I tap on the link:

> The invitation has already been redeemed. Please request a new invite
> from the developer

[image]

Any idea how to revoke my previous redemption code and generate a new one? The problem is that the TestFlight app does not have any sort of login button to let me log in and it shows the list of my projects under this account. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. There is a painful fact that I had to sign out of my personal account (Apple ID) and then sign in with my company email address. Doing this way, Testflight pulled the list of my pass automatically and I am able to install them.

Isn't there any way, like Android, to have both accounts together?

Comment: When an invitation code is redeemed, it is associated with the Apple ID that is logged in to the device at the time. You will need to add another tester via email in TestFlight in order to get another invitation code. You can then redeem that code while signed in to your personal Apple ID to associate it